# MapQuest in ASP.NET MVC generating extra request for null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapquest

I'm using MapQuest in a ASP.NET MVC application. Some errors started showing up in our logs in the one page where MapQuest is used, but the problem doesn't manifest during normal use of the application. It's kind of a bizarre problem so I'll step through what I've already done.

The error log shows the following:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in
>   'TheProject.Controllers.TheController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

It's a typical MVC Edit action:

`public ActionResult Edit(int id)`

And the way to replicate the problem is hitting it without and id or with an id that is not an int.
Since this shouldn't be happening, I turned to Chrome's Developer Tools to find out:

[image: Network traffic]

Note the "null" request there. That's a GET request for Edit/null which is invalid, and triggers the error mentioned at the start.

My question is, why and how is that request being generated? Everything points to MapQuest because it doesn't happen on any other areas of the application. Also, it shows up in the middle of all the other request related to MapQuest, and always immediately after one of these:

> https://open.mapquestapi.com/logger/v1/transaction?transaction=log&t=m&c=1&c2=1&s=6770&lat=53.292660000000005&lng=-9.005374&key=XXXXX,rs=XXXXX&width=775&height=500&rand=6794&v=JS_7.0.s_MQ&r=

Any ideas on what causes this behaviour and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer I got in the MapQuest Developer Forums, it's a known issue in the MapQuest SDK:

> There is a request to a null resource in the MapQuest sdk that is a known issue, but there is no update planned to address this issue as development has moved from the MapQuest sdk to the plugins.

Full thread [here](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/invisible-extra-request-performed-when-mapquest-map-loads-0).